# Create reusable classes of effects with ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to reuse common [*effects*](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) in my NgRx Angular 6 application. Currently, I've extracted out an *effect* builder service that helps create the *effect* implementation. I'd like to reduce the duplicate code even more though. Is it possible to dynamically build and register *effects* without the declarative `@Effect()` decorator, or some other way?

Here's an example of two *effect* classes I have, one for each module in my app. They're essentially the same except for some configuration data passed to the `buildEffectX()` methods:

*Module**1**Effects* class:

```
@Injectable()
export class Module1Effects {

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private effectsBuilder: MyEffectsBuilder) { }

    @Effect()
    effect1$: Observable<Action> = this.effectsBuilder.buildEffect1(this.store, "Module1");

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    effect2$: Observable<Action> = this.effectsBuilder.buildEffect2(this.store, "Module1");

    @Effect()
    effect3$: Observable<Action> = this.effectsBuilder.buildEffect3(this.store, "Module1");
}
```

*Module**2**Effects* class:

```
@Injectable()
export class Module2Effects {

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private effectsBuilder: MyEffectsBuilder) { }

    @Effect()
    effect1$: Observable<Action> = this.effectsBuilder.buildEffect1(this.store, "Module2");

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    effect2$: Observable<Action> = this.effectsBuilder.buildEffect2(this.store, "Module2");

    @Effect()
    effect3$: Observable<Action> = this.effectsBuilder.buildEffect3(this.store, "Module2");
}
```

I'd like to reduce this boilerplate even further if possible. Is there a way forward here or does the declarative nature of `@Effect()` mean that I have to do it this way?

Comment: Let me ask you, why do you need to create reusable effects? I believe that it's possible to achieve what you need with composition.

Comment: Because my app has multiple lazy-loaded modules that do many similar things. For example, I might have a BooksModule and there's an effect that runs a report on books. And then I might have a SocksModule and there's an effect that runs a report on socks. In each module, the pattern is the same, an effect that intercepts common action types (Like RunReportAction) and then calls an API. Then, the effect sends an action with the results (ReportResultsReadyAction).

Comment: We have very similar cross-cutting functionality like load comments or attachments for different kind of components. And the best way to achieve it is to publish another action like ``RunReportAction(reportType, correlationId: guid)`` and then wait for response. You may read about this pattern here https://medium.com/default-to-open/angular-splitter-and-aggregation-patterns-for-ngrx-effects-c6f2908edf26